# AWS Lambda Layer - Signature Expired Error (for a 5MB upload)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers, aws-signature

I'm trying to upload dependencies to my lambda layer. The zip file is 5MB in size (half of what is suggested to be uploaded to S3) but I still keep getting the error:

```
Failed to create layer version: Signature expired: 20240206T173642Z is now earlier than 20240206T174039Z (20240206T174539Z - 5 min.)
```

I tried giving it time but still get the same error the next day. Previously, I used to give it an hour or 2 and the error would automatically go away. But this time it is persisting.

Comment: Have you tried uploading your dependencies to S3 first?